# Boostrap dynamic tabs hide and show button using if else

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**what I am trying to archive is:**

if I am in **home** hide all buttons

if I am in **menu 1** open buttons from **menu1**

if I am in **menu 2** open buttons from **menu2**

**sample working:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/FygL9aUL1rzgElsx59Di?p=preview

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pull-right menu1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
</div>

<div class="pull-right menu2" style="display:none;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">new</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried? What failed?

Comment: And as a side note, who upvoted this 30 seconds after posting? Seems suspicious.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use [ngStyle] or [ngClass], and set the styles you want dynamically when a given view loads? If you don't know what those two things are all about, most definitely (like most, most definitely) look them up. They are extremely powerful capabilities that do exactly what you're asking here, in fact they make dynamic styling of anything anywhere in the app fairly simple.

Comment: i can't use Angular for this, just jquery

Comment: Oh...then just get the elements you want to toggle using your jquery or DOM selector (querySelector or whatever), and set the CSS properties dynamically that way (look up "changing styles Javascript"). This is more or less what ngClass and ngStyle do anyway, they just make it bindable. Same idea though. Select the element, modify the CSS/styles according to the tech you're using (jquery, plain DOM, whatever). In your case you'd alter the "display" style (hidden or blank) in order to make sure the hidden buttons don't take up space (or if you want them to, use "visibility").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to change the `data-target` on the tabs to a class instead of a single element by id. That way each tab will control multiple `tab-pane` targets.

Demo - http://www.codeply.com/go/ZnZXMlyfaF

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target=".home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target=".menu1" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target=".menu2" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="home tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="menu1 tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="menu2 tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container tab-content">
    <div class="pull-right home tab-pane">
        <!-- empty show nothing -->
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right menu1 tab-pane">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right menu2 tab-pane">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">new</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo - http://www.codeply.com/go/ZnZXMlyfaF

Comment: thank you, for you very useful help, i really appreciate, specially for someone with no much knowledge in js and jquery